# Algebra of block matrices with scalar diagonals

Tags: reference-request, linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-theory, block-matrices

I am interested in block matrices $A$, *that is $A\in M_{n\times n}(R)$ where $R=M_{s\times s}(k)$ and $k$ is a field*, such that for every positive integer $m$ the matrix $A^m$ has only scalar blocks on the diagonal.

If we view $A$ as an $ns\!\times\! ns$ matrix - has the characteristic polynomial of $A$ be of the form $p(x)^s$, where $p(x)$ is a degree $n$ polynomial?

Essentially the only ways I could construct such a matrix is:

1. take a Quaternion Hermitian matrix or
2. start with a block diagonal matrix with scalar blocks on the diagonal and conjugate it by a generalized Hadamard matrix $H$ (the $s\times s$ blocks of $H$ are orthogonal matrices and $H*H^T=nI$). I would expect that there should be other methods.

Is there any literature on such  matrices available?

Comment: $\left[\begin{matrix} 0&B\cr B^{-1}&0\end{matrix}\right]$ is such a matrix, for any invertible matrix $B$.